# How to extract sub-string from Haystack's print_answers

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers, large-language-model, haystack

I was following this tutorial from [pinecone.io](https://www.pinecone.io/learn/haystack-lfqa/) about using Haystack's `print_answers`

And as you can see in the later part of the tutorial, the output carries a lot of string. These string like output is not subscript-able and thus I'm not able to index or slice them

 
[image]

How can I select the text from the output, and display only a desired part, e.g. only this part of the output
[image]

Blog Link: [Long Form Question Answering in Haystack](https://www.pinecone.io/learn/haystack-lfqa/) 
Sample Code Notebook: [Google Colab NB](https://colab.research.google.com/github/deepset-ai/haystack-tutorials/blob/main/tutorials/01_Basic_QA_Pipeline.ipynb)

Answer (score 1):

You can get the Answer with this command:
`result['answers'][0].answer`.

However, that tutorial is quite outdated.
I suggest a more recent tutorial with a similar topic and better performance: [Creating a Generative QA Pipeline with Retrieval-Augmentation](https://haystack.deepset.ai/tutorials/22_pipeline_with_promptnode).